# ¿Cómo rellenar matrices con números reales aleatorios?

Tags: c++, matrices, bucles

Debo llenar 2 matrices con números reales desde el -100.00 a 100.00 con dos decimales, pero solo puedo lograr que se impriman enteros del negativos de 0 a 100.

Son matrices cuadradas.

Tengo este 'loop' para llenar una que básicamente es el que usé para las dos:

```
  srand(time(NULL));

 for(int i=0;i<number;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<number;j++)
    {

        num=-100+rand()%100;
        matrix[i][j]=num;
    }
```

Comment: creo que lo correcto es : `num=-100+rand()%201` pero eso solo te producirá números enteros, habría que ver como inicializaste `num` y `matrix`.

Comment: ya intente inicializando num y matrix como float  y luego como double y no puedo me da error de que un double no es compatible con un int, el srand es int?

Comment: el argumento de `srand` es un `unsigned int` (entero sin signo, es decir positivo), es la semilla para los números aleatorios, `rand() % n`  con `n` entero te devuelve un número entero entre cero y n-1

Answer (score 6):

El problema es que `num = -100 + rand() % 100` tiene un rango de `[-100, -1]` por lo siguiente: `rand() % 100` tiene un rango de `[0, 99]`, si después a ese rango se le suma `-100`, el rango final será `[-100 + 0, -100 + 99] = [-100, -1]`. Es por esto que ves solamente enteros negativos.

Para generar valores entre `[-100.00, 100.00]` podrías hacer lo siguiente:

1. Generar un valor aleatorio entre `[0, 20 000]` con

```
rand() % 20001
```

2. Dividir ese valor generado sobre `100`, esto para obtener los dos decimales, y el número quedará en el rango `[0, 200.00]` con

```
(rand() % 20001) / 100
```

3. Luego para que quede en el rango de `[-100.00, 100.00]` simplemente le puedes restar `100`.

```
(rand() % 20001) / 100 - 100
```

Nótese por qué al inicio se eligió un aleatorio entre `[0, 20 000]`, si hubiéramos elegido uno entre `[0, 10 000]` en este paso estaríamos cayendo en la misma situación de sólo ver negativos.

Finalmente quedaría algo así en código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
        num = (rand() % 20001) / 100.0f - 100.0f;
        matrix[i][j] = num;
    }
}
```

Por último, lo anterior diría que es más código "C" que C++, si estás usando C++, quizá sea mejor idea optar por usar [random](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/) y alguna de sus clases como [`uniform_real_distribution`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/uniform_real_distribution/). Un ejemplo rápido:

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::default_random_engine generator(time(nullptr));
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distribution(-100.0f,100.0f);

    int number = 100;
    float matrix[number][number]; // probablemente si es c++ tambien sea oportuno usar std::array

    // llenar la matriz
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = distribution(generator);
        }
    }

    // imprimir la matriz
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < number; j++) {
            std::cout << matrix[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: `rand() % 20000 + 1` es de `[1, 20 000]` no de `[0, 20 000]`, debería incluirse el cero.

Comment: Cierto, cierto, gracias por la observación, corregido

Answer (score 1):

La función rand() te genera un numero entero desde 0 hasta el numero que le indicas.

[Aqui](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/) la documentación.

```
v1 = rand() % 100;         // v1 in the range 0 to 99
v2 = rand() % 100 + 1;     // v2 in the range 1 to 100
v3 = rand() % 30 + 1985;   // v3 in the range 1985-2014
```

Lo que podrías hacer es generar numeros del 0 al 20 001 y dividirlo entre 100

Algo como esto

```
num=-100+ ((rand() % 20001)/100);
```

Comment: creo que con eso impides la aparición del cero en los números aleatorios, con lo cuál nunca me daría -100.

Comment: Si `num` es del tipo `float` o `double`, la expresión correcta debe ser: `num=-100.00+ ((rand() % 20001)/100.00);`

Comment: creo que si en lugar de poner 20000 + 1 lo dejas como 20001 funciona, creo que el +1 se aplica al final del computo, por lo que es lo que te da rand mas 1, pero si le indicas el 20001 te genera 20001 numeros empezando por el cero y terminando en el 20000

Comment: claro la idea es que toda la expresión nos de un número de -100 a 100, son 20001 números de 0 a 20000 que divididos por 100 te dan un número entre 0 y 200, que disminuidos en 100 daría un número entre -100 y 100, quee cubre todo el intérvalo deseado.

Comment: **NO, No, no**. La utilidad `rand` no debe usarse en C++. Además, hacer módulo sobre un valor que no es múltiplo del rango de resultados falsea ligeramente el resultado.

Comment: Bueno, el libro que uso como base es el de Deitel "Como programar C++", hay una sección en el capítulo 6 de generación de números aleatorios, donde utilizan `rand` y `srand`, la que tengo es la sexta edición, creo no es una edición actualizada. ¿hay algún problema con el uso de `rand` en C++?