# Cómo llenar una matriz de enteros sujeta a reestricciones matemáticas según su fila y columna

Tags: c, matrices

Estoy trabajando en Dev-C++, y me han pedido que llene una matriz de 5x5 con las siguientes especificaciones:

1. Los elementos que estén en las filas y columnas impares serán llenados con valores aleatorios entre 25 y 100, y que sean múltiplos de 5.
2. Los elementos de fila y columna par serán llenados  con valores aleatorios entre 50 y 120 y que sean múltiplos de 3.
3. El resto de elementos serán serán llenados  con valores aleatorios entre 80 y 150, y que sean múltiplos de 7.

Es decir, que la matriz quedaría algo así (Los elementos de la instrucción 1 los señalo con paréntesis, los de la instrucción 2 con guiones, y los del "resto" no llevan nada, para tener un mejor entendimiento.):

```
(100)    91     (85)    84     (55)
140     -57-    133    -57-    119
(70)     98     (65)    119    (35)
105     -45-    112    -60-    126
(30)     140    (75)    147    (90)
```

El problema es que no sé exactamente cómo hacer para que se haga este llenado, pues soy nuevo en esto. Solamente he podido hacer que una parte de la instrucción 1, haciendo que todas las filas impares tengan elementos con valores aleatorios entre 25 y 100, y que son múltiplos de 5, pero de ahí no logro hacer lo demás. En seguida presento mi código:

```
#include<time.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int arr[5][5],i,j,random;
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            random=rand()%(100-25)+25;
            if(i%2==0&&random%5==0)
            {
                arr[i][j]=random;
            }
            else if(i%2!=0&&random%5!=0)
            {
                arr[i][j]=random;
            }
            else
            {
                j--;
            }
        }
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Checa esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/326185/c%c3%b3mo-rellenar-matrices-con-n%c3%bameros-reales-aleatorios/326202#326202) lo único que cambia es el rango de los números y la posición en la matriz, pero por lo que veo ese ya no es problema.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este problema veo que es más algebraíco que de programación en sí.

Basta que modifiques un poco tu primer for para cumplir las 3 condiciones.
La explicación está al final de la sección **TL;TR**

```c
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            int fpar = (i + 1) % 2 == 0; // fila par
            int cpar = (j + 1) % 2 == 0; // columna par

            if (!fpar && !cpar) // fila y columna impar
            {
                arr[i][j] = 5 * (rand() % 16) + 25; // multiplos de 5 en el intervalo [25, 100]
            }
            else if (fpar && cpar) // fila y columna par
            {
                arr[i][j] = 3 * (rand() % 24) + 51; // multiplos de 3 en el intervalo [50, 120]
            }
            else // otros
            {
                arr[i][j] = 7 * (rand() % 10) + 84; // multiplos de 7 en el intervalo [80,150]
            }
        }
    }
```

---

## TL;TR

**(1.)**

- Para que un número `x` sea múltiplo de 5, se debe de poder expresar como `x(n) = 5n` donde `n` es un número entero positivo.
- Para generar múltiplos de 5 en el rango [25, 100] basta desplazar la función anterior por 25 unidades `x(n) = 5n + 25` y reestringir el dominio a 0 <= n <= 15.

Pseudocódigo:

```c
    x = 5 * (rand() % 16) + 25;
```

**Nota**: debe ser `rand() % 16` y no `rand() % 15` puesto que `15 % 15` daría como resultado `0`  no obstante, 15 pertenece al dominio anterior. En general, debes hacer `rand() % (max - min + 1)`, si el intervalo deseado es [min, max] o bien `rand() % (max - min)` si el intervalo deseado es [min, max) sin incluir a max

---

**(2.)**

- Para que un número `x` sea múltiplo de 3, se debe de poder expresar como `x(n) = 3n`.
- El rango provisto en este inciso es [50, 120] no obstante 50 no es múltiplo de 3, así que el rango real es [51, 120] siendo el 51 el primer multiplo de 3 y 120 el último.
- Para genera múltiplos de 3 en el rango [51, 120] se debe desplazar la función 51 unidades `x(n) = 3n + 51` y reestringir el dominio a `0 <= n <= 23`

Pseudocódigo:

```c
    x = 3 * (rand() % 24) + 51;
```

---

**(3.)**

- Para que un número `x` sea múltiplo de 7, se debe de poder expresar como `x(n) = 7n`.
- El rango provisto en este inciso es [80, 150] no obstante ninguno de los dos es múltiplo de 7, así que el rango real es [84, 147] siendo el 84 el primer multiplo de 7 y 147 el último.
- Para generar múltiplos de 7 en el rango [84, 147] se debe desplazar la función 84 unidades `x(n) = 7n + 84` y reestringir su dominio a `0 <= n <= 9`

Pseudocódigo:

```c
    x = 7 * (rand() % 10) + 84;
```

---

## Salidas

Adjunto algunas salidas del programa.

```
$ ./main.exe
( 65)    105    ( 40)    105    ( 35)
 133    - 75-    133    - 69-     98
( 75)    133    ( 85)    112    ( 95)
 147    - 51-     84    - 66-    133
( 70)     91    (100)    140    ( 70)
```

```
$ ./main.exe
( 80)     91    ( 80)    147    ( 90)
 119    -102-     84    -114-    112
( 55)     91    ( 60)    105    ( 95)
 147    - 57-    133    - 87-    105
( 30)     98    ( 55)     98    ( 45)
```

```
$ ./main.exe
( 95)    147    ( 40)    112    ( 60)
  98    - 78-    105    -114-    126
( 35)    119    ( 35)    147    ( 95)
 147    - 63-    112    -108-    140
( 65)    119    ( 90)    133    (100)
```

Comment: En serio te lo agradezco muchísimo, exactamente eso necesitaba. Excelente respuesta.

Comment: Disculpa, tengo una última pregunta: En la línea 7 del código que escribiste (la que dice "if (!fpar && !cpar)"), ¿Por qué has escrito ese signo de admiración antes de "fpar" y "cpar", pero luego en la línea 11 no están esos signos? ¿Qué función cumplen los signos de admiración en esa línea (la 7) en especial?

Comment: El signo `!` sirve para negar el valor anterior, así `!fpar` significa "fila NO par" es decir "fila impar". Así la condición `if (!fpar && !cpar)` significa "si fila impar y columna impar..."

Comment: Ahh, ok. Muchas gracias, buen día.